# capistrano/deprec using :user instead of :svn_username to log into svn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, deployment, capistrano

I'm using deprec with password-protected svn.  I need to use a different login/pass for svn than for logging into the server.  The deprec way to do that is :svn_username, as far as I can tell, but it doesn't seem to be working. deprec (2.0.13), capistrano (2.5.8).  Snip of deploy.rb / bash: http://pastie.org/pastes/545876

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `:scm_user` and `:scm_password`.

Comment: FYI, my deploy was failing (or hanging on svn username) because I was using :scm_user. The docs stipulate :scm_username, which I changed it to and it worked.